# How to implement c++ linkedlist constructors?

Tags: c++

So im currently trying to convert my c linked list data structure into a c++ and I'm having a bit of trouble with constructors and implementing the code. Here is what I have for my node class:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
  public:
    T item
    LinkedList::Node<T>* next;
    Node();
    ~Node();
};
```

Here is my lLinked List class:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList {
  private:
    linkedlist::Node<T>* head;
    linkedlist::Node<T>* tail;
  public:
    size_t length;
     LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();//deconstructor
    size_t insertAtTail(T item);
    size_t insertAtHead(T item);
    size_t insertAtIndex(size_t index, T item);
    T removeTail();
    T removeHead();
    T removeAtIndex(size_t index);
};
```

And this is how I wrote the code for the constructors: EDIT: removed void from LinkedList because I forgot too

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    Node<T> node(NULL);
    head = node;
    tail = node;
}

//Create node and return reference of it.

 Node<T>::Node(T item) {
    Node* nNode = NULL;

    
    nNode->item = item;
    nNode->next = NULL;

    return nNode;
}
```

I keep getting a type error for Node and a "argument list for class template "`LinkedList" is missing`" for LinkedList. It seems a bit complicated and I'm not really understanding how too go about this. Like why cant I just implement the code for the header methods in the header method instead of having to do in in a different file and including the header file. Any tips, helps, etc. are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `void` from the `LinkedList::LinkedList()` constructors don't have a return type .

Comment: Would I also have to use maloc for the constructors? I'm assuming so, im just not sure about my LinkedList constructuor

Comment: Seems you have basic issues. Try to use constructor for simpler classes (no template, no pointers) first.

Comment: No, `LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>()` would work, same as `LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>()`, The `()` is the constructor, `<int>` is to specify the `T` of the template.

Comment: Remove the creation of the node in your constructor, and simple set `head = tail = nullptr`. Also, since LinkedList is a template, you need `template<class T>` before you define the constructor.

Comment: @ChrisMM Oh so would it just be `this->head = this-> tail = NULL;` for my LinkedList Constructor?

Comment: Yes, that way the list is empty to begin with, instead of pointing to a node. But, again, you need the template before, so `template <class T> LinkedList::LinkedList() {...}`

Comment: @Aviera00 not `NULL`, `nullptr`. If someone is teaching you to use `NULL`, they are teaching you bad C++

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should be prefixed with template keyword and also include type T, something like this:

```
template <class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
    head = node;
    tail = node;
}
```

Also, you must create node variable on heap, the way you wrote it will use local variable from stack to initialize class members.

Comment: This won't compile; you have some typos in there. Also, initially the list won't be empty.

Comment: This is just showing conceptually how the error should be fixed. Fixing typos and how the list should be initialized is up to the actual implementation.

Comment: What you posted is incorrect, and leads to more errors  ... The header should be `template <class T> LinkedList::LinkedList()` ...